# Where would one put a JNI module in Linux or OS X

Tags: java, linux, macos, java-native-interface

The Java application has the JNI module to use.

Where should a user (or an installation script of this application) put the JNI module on Linux (Ubuntu) or on MacOS X so that this JNI module could be loaded without specifying the path to the module in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the compiled libraries (.so files on Linux or .dylib on MacOS) into a directory of your choice and include this directory in the library search path LD_LIBRARY_PATH used to start your JVM.

Comment: Please note that OS X has different naming convention for shared libs. You don't have "so" files in OS X. There are "dylib" files.

Comment: Thanks @mko, I have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This is a link to a [detailed explanation](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) of shared objects and how they are searched for by the OS.

I wish Java people would stop using LD_LIBRARY_PATH and start using the existing directory structures and the ld.so.conf mechanism.  Even the OpenJDK libraries are dumped in a place that's not on a standard path and they don't add an ld.so.conf file either ( just how hard is that ? ).

This approach avoids the need to set up your own LD_LIBRARY_PATH and launch via a shell script.

If a required shared object is to be installed, first test for somewhere like `/usr/local/lib` as an installation choice system wide, and if it exists and an existing file does not already use your file's name, then put your library there.  A more systematic approach would be to check all the ld.so.conf files and see if any of the directories match something you know can be used.  A shell script can do that at install time.